# Adding singlechildscrollview hiding all widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, singlechildscrollview

If I add a SingleChildScrollView in this Flutter screen, all my widgets disappear. I get a blank white screen. This is my code without scroll:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 33),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/top_right.png"), //Icon
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -10,
              right: 0,
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/profile_picture.png"),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                child: const Text(
                                  "Hi,",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "poppin_regular",
                                      fontSize: 27,
                                      color: Colors.black),
                                )),
                            Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                child: const Text(
                                  "Jennifer",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                      fontSize: 40,
                                      color: Colors.black),
                                ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                            elevation: 1,
                            shadowColor: Colors.black,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 305,
                                  height: 50,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                                    child: TextField(
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        hintText: "Search For Place",
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                140, 140, 140, 100)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ), //Padding
                                ),
                                Image.asset("assets/images/search.png")
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: Text(
                                "What are you looking for",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                    fontSize: 18),
                              )),
                          Container(
                            height: 133,
                            width: 345,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xffa3a3a3),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(10),
                                )),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset("assets/images/Group 509.png"),
                                    const Text(
                                      "Request a trip",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                          fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: const [
                                            Text(
                                              "When new trip matches your travel ",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "needs Get Notified",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                            height: 71,
                                            width: 90,
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                                "assets/images/Group 539.png"))
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 133,
                            width: 345,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xffffdacb),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(10),
                                )),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => PostYourTrip(),
                                    ));
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset("assets/images/orangedots.png"),
                                    const Text(
                                      "Post your trip",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                          fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          children: const [
                                            Text(
                                              "Let others know about your plan so ",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "they can join you on your journey ",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                            height: 71,
                                            width: 90,
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                                "assets/images/post_trip.png"))
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 133,
                            width: 345,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xffbde4fe),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(10),
                                )),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => FindTrip(),
                                    ));
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset("assets/images/bluedot.png"),
                                    const Text(
                                      "Find your trip",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                          fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: const [
                                            Text(
                                              "Find a ride and carpool anywhere in",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "Pakistan",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                  fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                            height: 71,
                                            width: 90,
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                                "assets/images/postgroup.png"))
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I add a `SingleChildScrollView` in top after or before the padding  widget, all the widgets disappear.

Please Check and provide me a solution. Thanks

Comment: Please share code with SIngleChildScrollView widget that you are trying to apply.

Comment: there is no SingleChildScrollView in the above code,
it usually happens because of the infinite height or width taken by the child widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code and replace my network image with your asset image

Flow of code:

```
Padding
  - Stack 
   - Positioned 
      - SingleChildScrollView 
         - Column 
           - Other Widgets
```

Full Code:

```
 Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 33),
    child: Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Image.network(
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
            height: 20,
          ), //Icon
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: -10,
          right: 0,
          child: Image.network(
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
            height: 20,
          ),
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: const Text(
                              "Hi,",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "poppin_regular",
                                  fontSize: 27,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            )),
                        Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                            child: const Text(
                              "Jennifer",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                  fontSize: 40,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      elevation: 1,
                      shadowColor: Colors.black,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 305,
                            height: 50,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                              child: TextField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: "Search For Place",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                          140, 140, 140, 100)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ), //Padding
                          ),
                          Image.network(
                            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "What are you looking for",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "poppin_semibold", fontSize: 18),
                        )),
                    Container(
                      height: 133,
                      width: 345,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xffa3a3a3),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Image.network(
                                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                "Request a trip",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                    fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: const [
                                      Text(
                                        "When new trip matches your travel ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "needs Get Notified",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                    height: 71,
                                    width: 90,
                                    child: Image.network(
                                      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
                                      height: 20,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 133,
                      width: 345,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xffffdacb),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Image.network(
                                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                "Post your trip",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                    fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: const [
                                      Text(
                                        "Let others know about your plan so ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "they can join you on your journey ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                    height: 71,
                                    width: 90,
                                    child: Image.network(
                                      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
                                      height: 20,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 133,
                      width: 345,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xffbde4fe),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          )),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Image.network(
                                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                "Find your trip",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontFamily: "poppin_semibold",
                                    fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: const [
                                      Text(
                                        "Find a ride and carpool anywhere in",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Pakistan",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontFamily: "poppin_regular"),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                                    height: 71,
                                    width: 90,
                                    child: Image.network(
                                      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png",
                                      height: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put some fixed width and height because you already trying to wrap an infinite height widget into an infinite height widget i.e stack -> singlechildscrollview. so what you have to do is you need to fix the inside widget height , i have putted a container with width and height as example

```
  Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.70,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column( your containers here )))
```